# How to specify path to the cookbook in the repo in chef policy file

Tags: chef-infra

I got a repo inside which my cookbook resides. I need to specify the **path** to the cookbook inside that repo. Someting like that:

```
cookbook 'my-cookbook', git: 'ssh://git@git.repo-url:7999/cc/my-cookbook.git/path/to/the/cookbook', branch: my-branch
```

Comment: As far as I am concerned, chef will look for the cookbook's metadata at the very root of the git repository. So I would use one Git repository per cookbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried with policies but for Berkshelf it would be `rel: 'path/to/cookbook'` and they use the same installer system so it should work I think.